# Given $k$ balls and $n$ buckets where $k\geq n$. What is the expected value of number of balls in bucket $i$

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Given $k$ balls and $n$ buckets where $k\geq n$. Each ball is thrown, and with probability $p$ it lands in one of $n$ buckets. Each bucket is equally likely.

Let $X_i$ be a random variable represent number of ball in bucket $i$ What is the $E[X_i]?$

I assumed that success means the ball is actually in the bucket. I've tried finding $E[X_i]$ through $E[X] = E[X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n]$. I feel like I'm going in wrong direction.

I've also tried $E[X] = kp$, so $E[X_i] = (kp)/n$

Comment: How do you define "success"?

Comment: Yes, as defined, we don’t know what success means, nor if each bucket is equally likely.

Comment: Fail is if you miss any of the bucket.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: A careful way of writing what you have written: Each ball is thrown, and with probability $p$ it lands in one of $n$ buckets. Each bucket is equally likely. As written, the question doesn’t seem to rely on $k\geq n.$ Is there a second part of the question in the source which asks what the probability $P(X_i>0)$ is?

Comment: This is the only part of the question. It only said that for each throw the success probability is p. So, I assumed that success means the ball is actually in the bucket. I've tried finding E[Xi] through E[X] = E[X1 + X2 + ... + Xn]. I feel like I'm going in wrong direction.

Comment: I would have let $S_i$ to denote the number of times you tossed a ball towards bucket $i$. Then $S_i\sim\text{Binomial}\left(k,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $X_i|S_i\sim \text{Binomial}(S_i,p)$. With this you can compute $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ using total law of expectation

Comment: I've also tried E[X] = kp, so E[Xi] = (kp)/n